# CSV reader using StreamReader and LINQ

Tags: c#, performance, linq, csv

Mostly due to readability, I am using the following code to

1. find a specific csv file on a drive
2. read that CSV file using a streamReader
3. parse it into a `List<string[]>` to be able to use LINQ and/or PLINQ later on

However, the process takes about 4-5 seconds, which is simply put too long. Any suggestions on how to improve the following (or maybe even replace it)?

```
var query = (from x in Directory.GetFiles(_path, "*.csv").AsParallel()
                     where x.Contains(dateTime)
                     select x).First();


        #region Read CSV File
        List<string[]> _tempList = new List<string[]>();

        FileStream stream = new FileStream(query, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.Default, true, 1024))
        {
            string currentLine;
            while ((currentLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] temp = currentLine.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                _tempList.Add(temp);
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

The order inside the CSV file is important - the file will contain between (2000-7000) x 25 entries.

The CSV file has several fields which I am not interested in - and I don't necessarily need them in my `List<string[]>` (or `string[][]`).  I have tried to filter them with a LINQ statement similar to the following pseudo code:

```
var query = from x in MyListOfStringArray
            select new {Col1 = x[1] , Col2 = c[4]}.ToArray();
```

This approach results in a strange type for query - and for that matter was pretty slow (I would have an array with about 9-11 properties).  Any ideas on that second issue?

Comment: Are you sure you're timing the correct part of the code (ie not including `query`)? I generated a test file of 7,000 lines, 25 entries per line, and your code runs in < 0.02s.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ```
> var query = (from x in Directory.GetFiles(_path, "*.csv").AsParallel()
>                      where x.Contains(dateTime)
>                      select x).First();
> ```

If `Directory.GetFiles(_path, "*.csv")` doesn't return any files `where x.Contains(dateTime)`, this line will blow up with an [InvalidOperationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/vstudio/bb291976(v=vs.100).aspx) that might be a bit off-putting / surprising.

I find the query would be clearer with a 100% method syntax - this would be equivalent:

```
var query = Directory.GetFiles(_path, "*.csv")
                     .AsParallel()
                     .Where(name => name.Contains(dateTime))
                     .First();
```

The name `query` is wrong/misleading. It would be a *query* if it were an `IQueryable<string>` (i.e. up to right after the `.Where()` call)... but it's not, `var` actually stands for `string` and what you call `query` is actually a `fileName`: `.First()` *materializes* the query, and returns the first element... or throws an exception.

It would be better to call `.FirstOrDefault()`, which would make your result `null` if no files matched your search criteria.

I don't understand why you're using `var` here, given that you're using explicit types everywhere else.. especially since `var` is just a `string`. Don't get me wrong though: I prefer seeing `var` here... and everywhere else.

---

> ```
> #region Read CSV File
> ```

Using `#region` inside a method clearly says your method is doing more than one thing. Whenever you do that, you're missing a refactoring opportunity. Consider extracting a method here:

```
private string GetFileName(string formattedDateTime)
{
    return Directory.GetFiles(_path, "*.csv")
                    .AsParallel()
                    .Where(name => name.Contains(formattedDateTime))
                    .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

(lacking context to recommend passing in an actual `DateTime`)

That leaves you with a method that (hopefully) now only has this `#region` block, which is now completely redundant and can be discarded (if there's still more to it, extract methods as needed)

That said...

> ```
> FileStream stream = new FileStream(query, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
> using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.Default, true, 1024))
> ```

Disposing the `StreamReader` will also cleanly close and dispose the `FileStream`, but that is far from obvious unless you know it, and [if Jon Skeet says it's best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1065196/1188513) to put it in its own `using` block, then I can only agree with him.

---

Your code can use a variable (declared outside the loop's body) for the value separator: you're creating a new character array for every single row you're reading!

```
char[] separator = new char[] { ',' };
```

Or more succinctly:

```
var separator = new[] { ',' };
```

This makes the `temp` assignment even clearer/cleaner:

```
string[] temp = currentLine.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Looking at the `currentLine`, it's far from obvious what's going on here:

```
while ((currentLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
```

Using the result of an assignment rarely results in easily readable code. I like how it cleverly combines reading the next line into `currentLine` and verifying whether that's a `null` value though... so I'm not sure I'd recommend rewriting that part after all.

---

It's not clear what happens to your `List<string[]>` when you're done reading the file, so I'll assume you're just returning it. In that case, you could consider `yield`ing the results instead:

```
private IEnumerable<string[]> ReadCsv(string fileName)
{
    char[] separator = new[] { ',' };
    string currentLine;

    using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.Default, true, 1024))
    {
        while ((currentLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            yield return currentLine.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing! 
Thank you so much! I was really not prepared for both the quality and dedication of your post.

Comment: Always a pleasure! Make sure you take @mjolka's answer into account as well, he's got very good points too :)

Answer (score 6):

[`Encoding.Default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default(v=vs.110).aspx) is possibly not the correct encoding for the file (and may change over time). The `detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks` parameter you pass to the `StreamReader` constructor only helps if the file start with byte-order marks. You should know how your files are encoded, and pass the appropriate encoding, e.g. `Encoding.UTF8`.

A more concise way to read the lines of a file is `File.ReadLines`, though it doesn't specify `ReadWrite` share access (which is something I'm not sure you want, either).

As for timing, I generated a test file of 7,000 lines, 25 entries per line, and your code runs in < 0.02s (not including `query`). So my guess is that it's `query` that is taking most of your time. Try it without `AsParallel()` and see if that improves performance.

Comment: Thank you for your advise, I must admit that I don't know anything about encoding or what a byte-order marks is. 

I require the Share access - the file is being written to from someone else.

Comment: @Aeolus Suppose you're writing code to read a video file. You would need to know the format of the file: is it AVI, MP4, Ogg, etc? Similarly, when reading a text file you need to know the file's encoding: is it UTF-8, UTF-16, US-ASCII, etc?

Comment: Is there an easy way to find out ? My very short analysis leads to the conclusion that 80% of all cases UTF-8 is a pretty solid guess.